# In es2015, `const func = foo => bar` makes `func` a named function, how do you bypass this?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to get around this behavior?

```
> foo => bar;
[Function]
> const func = foo => bar;
undefined
> func
[Function: func]
```

I have code that temporarily stores an anonymous function like that, then returns it. I don't want the implementation detail of the variable name to be exposed like that.

Comment: What is the end result you want?

Comment: What's wrong with exposing it?

Comment: @7zark7 Referring to the repl example, `func` should display `[Function]` and `func.name` should be `''`. This is how it used to work in es5.

Comment: @KitSunde As the title says, this is about ES2015. `name` inference has been added which names a function based on how it is assigned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to avoid this without affecting your code structure is probably to use the identity function to wrap the definition:

```
const id = x => x;

const func = id( foo => bar );
console.log(func.name) // undefined
```

If you don't want to declare a helper function, you can inline it as well, or use an IIFE:

```
const func1 = (f=>f)( foo => bar );
const func2 = (()=> foo => bar )();
```

but basically anything [except the grouping operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-grouping-operator-static-semantics-isfunctiondefinition) (a parenthesised expression) will do:

```
const func3 = (0, foo => bar); // comma operator, known from indirect eval
const func4 = [foo => bar][0]; // member access on array literal
const func5 = true ? foo => bar : null; // ternary operator
```

<sub>(And while you're at it, don't forget to add an appropriate comment that explains why you're doing this)</sub>

Of course, that might not prevent a debugger or console from inferring some other, internal name for the function.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think the `id` is really doing anything here. You'd probably get the same result if you didn't have it.

Comment: @Asad: That's the point, it isn't really altering the semantics of the evaluation; yet it does alter the semantics of the syntax, by avoiding to put an anonymous function expression in the right hand side of the assignment, which prevents it from getting assigned a `.name`.

Comment: I'm testing this in Firefox, which AFAIK does have ES6. Just assigning the func as in OP's snippet doesn't set `.name` for the function, even without this `id` thing. Here's what I'm running: `const func = foo => bar; console.log(func.name);`. This logs `undefined` to the console.

Comment: @Asad: FF does not yet have full ES6 support (I don't know any engine that does). Especially, it [does not support function `.name` completely](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#function_name_property)

Comment: Interesting. Would an IIFE work here? i.e. `const func = (() => foo => bar)()`? Or would that still end up assigning the function a name?

Comment: Yes it does, I already wondered whether I should include that approach. Gonna edit.

Comment: `(f=>f)( foo => bar )` o_O

Comment: @zerkms: Not as bad as the Y combinator with arrow functions :-)

Comment: @Bergi the more complicated JS becomes - the more valued experienced JS developers are. And that's a good thing :-)

Comment: Or even `const func = (0, foo => bar);` if you want to avoid the IIFE/function call.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Oh how lame is that :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to ECMAScript.

It's true that, when you assign an anonymous function a variable, the `name` of the function will be set to the name of the variable (thanks @loganfsmyth for the correction).

Since `name` is a configurable property, you could delete it. However, that would be useless, because `name` is unrelated.

For example, Firefox hasn't implemented naming anonymous functions as the variables yet, so `name` is the empty string in your example. But the console still displays `function func()` when you log the function.

In fact, the "problem" is that browsers want to make debugging code easier, so their console infers a name (not necessarily the `name`) for the function.

[Engines can infer function names](http://astithas.com/talks/qconsf2013/#/18/2) gives this example of inference:

> Anonymous functions no longer need to be named for debugging
>
> ```js
> function f() {}            // display name: f (the given name)
> var g = function () {};    // display name: g
> o.p = function () {};      // display name: o.p
> var q = {
>   r: function () {}        // display name: q.r
> };
> function h() {
>   var i = function() {};   // display name: h/i
>   f(function () {});       // display name: h/<
> }
> var s = f(function () {}); // display name: s<
> ```

The consoles of the browsers are not standardized by ECMAScript, so you can't modify this behavior.

Comment: The `.name` property of functions *is* standardised though. And in a compliant environment, your function will get the name `"func"`.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, `name` is standardized. But the name displayed when a function is logged in the console is not.

Comment: Right, OP's code example (with the `[Function: func]`) is a misleading, I think he actually is looking for preventing the `.name` property to get attached

Comment: @Bergi Instead, I think OP wants to prevent the console from inferring a name for the function.

Comment: Hm, maybe, but that would not have anything to do with ES6.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, that's why I said "*This is not related to ECMAScript*" at the beginning of my answer :)

Comment: @Oriol So we're all on the same page, inferring the 'name' of a function for its usage is part of ES6. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation specifically "If hasNameProperty is false, perform SetFunctionName(rval, GetReferencedName(lref))." so it will name itself based on the name of the `lref` reference that it is being assigned to, which will be the variable name `func`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Interesting, I hadn't read that part of the spec and assumed Firefox implemented `name` properly. Anyway, what I said is still true: when you log a function to the console, you can't prevent it from inferring a name for the function (independently on whether it has a `name` or not).

Comment: OP's example does not apply in Firefox 42 and babel. `func.name` is `'func'`.